# Use OpenTelemetry with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, open-telemetry

I have been trying to use OpenTelemetry (https://opentelemetry.io/) in an Apache Flink's job. I am sending the traces to a Kafka topic in order to see it in a Jaeger.

The traceability is working in the job when I am executing it inside my IntelliJ IDE, but once I create the package and try to execute it inside the cluster, I am not able to make it work.
Is there any blocker in that sense for Apache Flink that I am not aware of?

I have accomplished this using a variable:

```
export FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:./lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar
```

But this is working if I am setting up the Flink's cluster. The problem it's that the cluster that I am using is inside AWS (Kinesis Analytics) and I am not able to set up this variable.

Is there a way to use OpenTelemetry with Flink?

Comment: Unless you can set the parameters in some kind of KDA option, I fear the answer is 'no'. KDA manages the jobmanager, taskmanagers themselves, so there is not much Flink can do.